# Can SQLLite support sorting by stroke or pronounciation?

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I'm dealing with some displaying issues when my android device lang is set to Japanese/Chinese, is there a way I can query the SQLite data order by pronunciation or stroke for asian words?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, the comparison/sorting algorithm is called a *collation*.

SQLite would allow to [define additional collations](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html) in its C API, but this is not exported in the Android SQLite API.

You could either

- read the data into memory and sort it in your code; or
- precompute a sorting key from your data and store it in a separate database field that you can use for sorting.